# Can not access Centos admin panel CWP Pro

Tags: centos7

I recently installed OpenVPN on my VPS (Centos 7) which runs on a different port(943).
Since then I am not able to access CWP Pro which runs on port(2031).
SSH and other services works perfectly.
Any idea on how i can fix that problem without reinstalling CWP Pro?

Answer (score 0):

Your copy of CWP pro may have expired. Run the update command `sh /usr/local/cwpsrv/htdocs/resources/scripts/update_cwp` on SSH shell.

You can login as root to change user configuration and change user password to access user accounts at `ip_address:2031`